# How to fetch events from Google Calendar API in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

Hey I am beginner in working with API's, I am trying to make a webapp which basically begins with Oauth login, and then fetches the events from Calendar. I made a basic login page with the help of this [blog](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/).

Now I am not sure how do I begin with? How do I use Google Calendar API's to fetch events. If someone could guide or provide some resources for beginners it would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a self-plug:

There is the [Google Calendar Simple API](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api) (gcsa) for Python (developed by me and other contributors). It is simple and Pythonic, object-oriented. It handles credentials, JSON formatting, datetimes/timezones, recurrence, etc. for you. Here is the [Getting started](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

1. [API Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference) - You can use the guide to make calls to the REST endpoints
2. [API Documentation for Python](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars)